# INPUT_SERVER returns null

Tags: php, superglobals, filter-input

I got weird results when I try to use `filter_input` with `INPUT_SERVER` (I am using PHP 5.6.9).

I run this code:

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
foreach (array_keys($_SERVER) as $varkey) {
     var_dump($varkey, filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, $varkey));
}
```

I get that every `filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, $varkey)` returns null. But `$_SERVER` have correct values.

Why that's happening?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a known PHP bug. Try this:

```
$result = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'SERVER_NAME');
/*
 * overcome bug filter_input some php versions would return null 
 * on some implementations of FCGI/PHP 5.4 and probably older 
 * versions as well.
 * 
 * https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49184
 */
if (empty($result) && isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) {
    $result = Filter::sanitize($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $filter);
}
```

This my wrapper until they fix this situation. Until then it must deal with it.

Comment: What is Filter::sanitize? Can you provide some documentation?