# filter_input returns no values for manually set entries in $_SERVER

Tags: php

I'm trying to programmatically set a value in `$_SERVER` and then read it back using `filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, ..)`, but `filter_input` does not return a result.

Can someone explain to me, why the following snippet is not working as I would expect it to work:

```
// define entry in $_SERVER:
$_SERVER['foo'] = 'bar';
echo $_SERVER['foo'] . PHP_EOL;     // prints 'bar' as expected

// but no results from filter_input...
$b = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'foo', FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW);
echo $b . PHP_EOL;    // empty

// ... or from filter_input_array
$a = filter_input_array(INPUT_SERVER, array('foo' => FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW));
echo $a['foo'] . PHP_EOL;   // empty

// filter_var_array works as expected, but why filter_input does not?
$a2 = filter_var_array($_SERVER, array('foo' => FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW));
echo $a2['foo'] . PHP_EOL;  // prints bar
```

Is `filter_input` not working directly on `$_SERVER` but rather on a copy obtained earlier?

Here is an online-version of the above minimal example: https://onlinephp.io/c/7cd0d

Comment: What does `var_dump()` give? 

Comment: var_dump($_SERVER) shows the entry (along with all the rest): `....  ["argv"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "test.php"
  }
  ["argc"]=>
  int(1)
  ["foo"]=>
  string(3) "bar"`

Comment: Perhaps it is your environment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php#127415 

Comment: Probable duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65662562/filter-input-input-server-request-uri-returning-null

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30827890/input-server-returns-null